# Powershell - compare Active Directory usernames with e-mail address

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, where-clause

I am currently trying to find all AD users that have been created using the model "firstname@domain.com" versus our new standard of "FirstInitialLastName@domain.com". I'm using the Quest ActiveRoles modules, specifically `Get-QADUser` to pull down my user details:

```
Get-QADUser -enabled -IncludedProperties PrimarySMTPAddress | ?{$_.Type -match "User"} | Select-Object FirstName,PrimarySMTPAddress ...
```

That gets me a list of user first names and their SMTP address. Where I am stumped is how to compare the results.

I thought normalizing the values (either adding "@domain.com" to the first name string or stripping "@domain.com" from the SMTP string) and then doing a -ieq test would be the best approach. I have found I can do the first with:

```
%{ $address=$($_.FirstName + "@domain.com";) }
```

But I can't figure out how to then test $address against the PrimarySMTPAddress string. I can create a second variable with:

```
%{ $smtp=$($_.PrimarySMTPAddress); }
```

and get the result:

```
[PS] C:\>$addy -ieq $smtp
True
```

I'm just unclear how to do it all in stream so that I can process my tree at once. If this is something that's just more suited to a script than a single line, that's fine too. Coming from the glorious world of BASH my brain just wanted to one-line it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-QADUser -Enabled -Email * -SizeLimit 0 | 
Where-Object {$_.Email.Split('@')[0] -eq $_.FirstName }
```

Comment: and there it is, so simple. all of my attempts using split were failing miserably. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-QADUser -enable -IncludedProperties PrimarySMTPAddress |
? { $_.PrimarySMTPAddress -match ("^"+[regex]::escape("$($_.firstname)")+"@domain.com") }
```